# Review deletion of answers for your own question - conflict of interest?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-delete

I recently got enough reputation to do reviews for low quality posts. So, I went to try it out, and ironically one of the first reviews was on an answer to a question I had asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627988/suppress-debug-output-of-setthreadname-exception-in-msvc)). I thought it was a low-quality answer, and I downvoted it and left comments on why I thought it was not a good answer. However, it seems that also being able to cast a vote to delete the answer is a conflict of interest.

'Ethically' should I skip the review? More generally, should users be asked to review answers to their own questions?

Comment: Now if you would have to review your own, possible low-quality answer, to some other persons question, that would be interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why someone would be more likely to want to keep a non-answer on their question any more than on another person's question, or why they'd want to try to delete a good answer.  There's just no incentive, as a result of it being your question, for you to act any differently than if it weren't your question.

On top of that, it still takes a lot of other users' votes to actually delete the content, so any marginal conflicts that might be there are still going to require the support of multiple other users.

Comment: "why they'd want to try to delete a good answer" I've handled my fair share of NAA flags by OPs who, based on their comments on the answers, flagged them because they didn't answer the question to their satisfaction, despite being proper answers. Presumably they just want that answer out of their sight.

Comment: However if an OP is using the review queue in the first place, it's much less likely for them to take such a highly subjective view on review items (unless they're robo-reviewing, of course, in which case - delete or greenlight all the things).

Comment: @BoltClock How many of the users casting those flags 1) have the privilege to use the LQP review queue and 2) actually use it?

Comment: As @BoltClock says, I think there are definitely reasons why an OP would want an answer deleted. Having less answers to your question might encourage more answers (especially if it was the only answer). They might get an answer they like better. I didn't realize that so many delete votes are required however - if that's the case, it seems less contentious.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito The odds of there being such a reviewer are *dramatically* lower than there just being a robo reviewer, so the net effect is simply going to be negligible.